# HTML CSS Navigation Bar trouble with Sub-Menu on mouse hover

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I built a navigation bar after studying the tutorials

from the website and following some demo examples. Now I

am stuck at one thing, the following is the code for my

navigation bar, and the code works fine except when

mouse is brought over one of the bars which has sub

menu. When done so, it gives flickering image of the

entire navigation bar without the result that it should

give. Please help me out in this and point me where I am

making the mistake?

This is the HTML Code for the navigation bar that I am

using:

```
<nav>
   <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
     <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
     <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">User Experience</a>
          <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cloud Computing</a></li>
      </ul>
         </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
  <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

The stylesheet for the following is this:

```
nav ul ul {
display: none; /*hides the unordered list inside the unordered list */
}

nav ul li:hover > ul { /*the > child selector makes sure only the child ul of the li being hovered is targeted, rather than all sub menus appearing at once.*/
    display: block; /*displays the hidden list when mouse is brought over it */ 
}






nav ul{
/* Affects the UL element */
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
}



nav ul li{
/* Specifying a fallback color and we define 

CSS3 gradients for the major browsers: */

background-color: #f0f0f0;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top, left bottom,from(#fefefe), color-stop(0.5,#f0f0f0),color-stop(0.51, #e6e6e6));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#fefefe 0%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e6e6e6 51%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#fefefe 0%,#f0f0f0 50%, #e6e6e6 51%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#fefefe 0%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e6e6e6 51%);
background-image: linear-gradient(#fefefe 0%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e6e6e6 51%);

border-right: 1px solid rgba(9, 9, 9, 0.125);

/* Adding a 1px inset highlight for a more polished efect: */

box-shadow: 1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255,0.6) inset;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) inset;

position:relative;

float: left;
list-style: none;
}

nav ul li:after{

/* This creates a pseudo element inslide each LI */ 

content:'.';
text-indent:-9999px;
overflow:hidden;
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:1;
opacity:0;

/* Gradients! */

background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(168,168,168,0.5)),color-stop(0.5,rgba(168,168,168,0)), to(rgba(168,168,168,0.5)));
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));
background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));
background-image:linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));

/* Creating borders with box-shadow. Useful, as they don't affect the size of the element. */

box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff,1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
-moz-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff,1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff,1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;

/* This will create a smooth transition for the opacity property */

-moz-transition:0.25s all;
-webkit-transition:0.25s all;
-o-transition:0.25s all;
transition:0.25s all;
}

/* Treating the first LI and li:after elements separately */

nav ul li:first-child{
border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

nav ul li:first-child:after,
nav ul li.selected:first-child:after{
box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
-moz-box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;

border-radius:4px 0 0 4px;
}

nav ul li:last-child{
border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}

/* Treating the last LI and li:after elements separately */

nav ul li:last-child:after,
nav ul li.selected:last-child:after{
box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff;
-moz-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 

#fff;

border-radius:0 4px 4px 0;
}

nav ul li:hover:after,
nav ul li.selected:after,
nav ul li:target:after{
/* This property triggers the CSS3 transition */
opacity:1;
}

nav ul:hover li.selected:after,
nav ul:hover li:target:after{
/* Hides the targeted li when we are hovering on the UL */
opacity:0;
}

nav ul li.selected:hover:after,
nav ul li:target:hover:after{
opacity:1 !important;
}

/* Styling the anchor elements */

nav ul li a{
color: #5d5d5d;
display: inline-block;
font: 20px/1 Lobster,Arial,sans-serif;
padding: 12px 35px 14px;
position: relative;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
z-index:2;
text-decoration:none !important;
white-space:nowrap;
} 


nav{
display: block;
margin: 300px auto 0;
text-align: center;
width: 600px;
}

a, a:visited {
text-decoration:none;
outline:none;
color:#54a6de;
```

}

```
a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: HINT: The 2nd level menu should be using absolute positioning.

Comment: When I use position:absolute in 2nd level menu, I get only the first sub-element and not the entire drop down list..

Comment: Other than positioning and visibility, use display:block and put all visual styling on the A-tags, not the LI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put additional styling for the sub-menu items

```
nav ul ul {
    padding-left:0;
}
nav ul ul li {
    float:none;
}
```

There was a problem that when you hovered, the layout changed and the hovered element escaped the mouse pointer, so it became "unhovered" again, hence the flicker.
Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/LeZuse/Zu47x/

Comment: and for the navigation not to change its width, I have to use fixed width for the navigation bars?

Comment: You need to set the parent item width so that all the children fit in. `nav ul li{width:200px;}` for example.